# как правильно использовать метод instanceof

Tags: java, ооп

Дана задача: Создать статический метод printMagazines(Printable[] printable) в классе Magazine, который выводит на консоль названия только журналов.  Создать статический метод printBooks(Printable[] printable) в классе Book, который выводит на консоль названия только книг. Используем оператор instanceof.
Метод написала, но его выполнение приводит к ошибке. Помогите пожалуйста :)
Код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 Printable[] test=new Printable[3];
 test[0]=new Book();
 test[1]=new Magazine("keke");
 test[2]=new Book();
        int k=0;
 for (Printable i:test){
     test[k].print();
k++;
 }
     **if   (test[k] instanceof Magazine){
         int l=0;
       ((Magazine) test[k]).printMagazines(test);
         k++;
     }**
    }}

public interface Printable {
    Printable print();
}

public class Book implements Printable {
    String name;
    @Override
    public Printable print() {
        System.out.println("1");
        return null;
    }
   public void printBooks(Printable[] printable){
       Printable b=print();
       System.out.println(b);
   }
}

public class Magazine implements Printable {
String name;
Magazine(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
    @Override
    public Printable print() {
        System.out.println("2");
        return null;
    }
   public void    printMagazines(Printable[] printable){
       System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Ошибка:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
at Main.main(Main.java:19)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `Метод написала, но его выполнение приводит к ошибке.` какой?

Comment: Отредактировала, спасибо!

Comment: `test[k]` это объект. Статический метод вызывается у класса.

Comment: что то вы с циклами мудрите. Вы определитесь, вам надо `for(int ik=0; k<3; k++)` или `for(Printable item : tests)`, сйечас у вас что то среднее между ними.

Comment: правильно его не использовать. по крайней мере пока не станете тим лидом))

Comment: Ваша ошибка не имеет отношения к instanceof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Magazine implements Printable {
  ...
  public static void printMagazines(Printable[] printables) {
    for (Printable p: printables) {
      if (p instanceof Magazine)
        p.print();
    }
  }
}

Magazine.printMagazines(test);
```

Comment: Ну вот раз и сразу ответ. Совсем никакой интриги :)

Comment: Спасибо Вам тоже! Спустя некоторое время поняла наводку:)

Comment: @Maria Пожалуйста. Успехов.